# How to use the class-validator conditional validation decorator (@ValidateIf) based on environment variable value

Tags: node.js, class-validator

I am trying to use the class-validator @ValidateIf conditional validator decorator based on the value of a environment variable. Let me share the code for better understanding:

// .env file entry

`AMOUNT_CHECK_IN_MODE=TEST`

In my validator(.dto) file, i have the following code placed

```
import {
   IsNumberString,
   Max,
   ValidateIf
} from 'class-validator';

export class GtTransactionDto {
 otherProperty: string;
 constructor() {
  this.otherProperty = process.env.AMOUNT_CHECK_IN_MODE;
}
 
 @ValidateIf(o => o.otherProperty === 'TEST')
  @Max(1, {
    message: 'Amount should not exceed 1',
    context: {
      code: GtTransactionErrorCode.validate.DestinationAmount
    },
  })
  @ValidateIf(o => o.otherProperty === 'LIVE')
  @IsNumberString(
    {},
    {
      message: 'This is not a valid $property number',
      context: {
        code: GtTransactionErrorCode.validate.DestinationAmount,
      },
    }
  )
  @ValidateIf(o => o.otherProperty === 'TEST')
  @IsNumberString(
    {},
    {
      message: 'This is not a valid $property number',
      context: {
        code: GtTransactionErrorCode.validate.DestinationAmount,
      },
    }
  )
  destinationAmount!: string; 
 }
```

**I want to make sure that in the if TEST is set as the value of AMOUNT_CHECK_IN_MODE in .env file, then the validation for max amount and isNumberString should run. However if the value is set to LIVE then only validation for isNumberString should run**

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Validation groups` and set the group based on the environment variable.

From the [docs](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#validation-groups)

```
import { validate, Min, Length } from 'class-validator';

export class User {
  @Min(12, {
    groups: ['registration'],
  })
  age: number;

  @Length(2, 20, {
    groups: ['registration', 'admin'],
  })
  name: string;
}

let user = new User();
user.age = 10;
user.name = 'Alex';

validate(user, {
  groups: ['registration'],
}); // this will not pass validation

validate(user, {
  groups: ['admin'],
}); // this will pass validation

validate(user, {
  groups: ['registration', 'admin'],
}); // this will not pass validation

validate(user, {
  groups: undefined, // the default
}); // this will not pass validation since all properties get validated regardless of their groups

validate(user, {
  groups: [],
}); // this will not pass validation, (equivalent to 'groups: undefined', see above)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
@ValidateIf(() => (process.env.AMOUNT_CHECK_IN_MODE === 'TEST'))
@Max(...) // Max validator runs only when AMOUNT_CHECK_IN_MODE === 'TEST'
@IsNumberString(...) // IsNumberString validator runs always
```